# What do the spine colors on the DC "New 52" issues indicate?

Tags: dc, the-new-52

So, I've started reading new 52 Batman franchise (Batman, Batman & Robin, Nightwing...) collections and I've noticed the New 52 books all have a colored pattern at the top of the spine. All Batman and Superman books are blue. Flash and Green Arrow books are red, and the various Green Lantern books have a green spine. I've also seen yellow/gold and dark gray variants but can't remember what publications they were on.

I'm kind of curious, do these colors signify some sort of sorting of stories, or were they just chosen for branding and aesthetic appeal?

[image]

Comment: From your description it seems obvious that these colours were chosen to aid people in selecting their fave brand when viewing from above.

Comment: @Richard - if you have a trade quote to that effect, that'd make an awsome answer. As it is, I'm leaning towards my theory that a chief editor's kids were accidentally let loose in the production/design room with a loose crayon box.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it sounds like you're noticing the various family groupings: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_52#Imprint_titles

Comment: @emachine That sounds like it, but it doesn't make sense given batman and superman are both blue. I suppose it's probably just Richard or even better, DVK's theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the colours represent the primary characters or teams.

- **Blue = Batman/Superman Family** (including Batwoman, Batgirl, The Joker and Harley Quinn)
- **Green = Green Lantern Corp**
- **Orange = Justice League** (including Wonder Woman, Shazam, The Flash and Aquaman).

That said, I've not been able to find a quote from DC to that effect, nor have I been able to confirm what colour the upcoming one-shots (several of which are from "families" not traditionally associated with any of the groupings listed above) will be.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Blue: Batman/Superman and all their friends E.g Super girl and Nightwing

Green: All Lanterns. White to black.

Red: BASICALLY EVERYONE. JL JLA JL3000 Stormwatch and all characters in those teams. Forever Evil.

Moroon/Burgundy: suicide squad

Orange: Teen Titans

Grey: JLD Constantine Swampthing Animal Man and trinity of sin

I'm pretty sure I got all the differnt colours in this.I think it is mainly about the storyline rather than specific characters like how all grey characters are connected by the Rot takeover storyline and red is just general.